# Store Google Location Place in SQLite

Tags: android

I'm using Google PlacePicker to pick specific place in my app. Then, I need to store that place in my SQLite db. Unfortunatelly Place is not serializable, so I can't put it as byte array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try storing lat lng in your db

```
PlacePicker.getLatLngBounds().
```

For more try [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Get your interested data from Place object and store them as a string in SQLite